# Why does the code skip the for-loop

Tags: java, for-loop

my task was to write a method that should combine letters which occur more then two times in a row. Example: ABBCCCDDDD -> ABBC3D4

I was told to us the library's In.java and Out.java for in and output. My problem is that the method skips the for-loop. I hope you can help me. If you have any questions about the code just ask me please

```
public class Aufgabe9_4 {
    static void codieren(String s){
        int Zähler = 0;
        char[] a = s.toUpperCase().toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i<s.length()-1; i++){
            if (a[i] == a[i+1] && a[i] ==a[i+2]){
                Zähler = 3;
                while (a[i] == a[i+Zähler]) Zähler++;   
                i = i + Zähler; 
            }
            Out.println(a[i] + Zähler);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Out.println("Geben sie eine Reihenfolge von Buchstaben ein!");
        String s = In.readString();
        Out.println("Die Codierung lautet:");
        codieren(s);
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you enter when the program paused for input?

Comment: Please DON'T use umlauts in your syntax!

Comment: We are not German speakers

Comment: Why no umlauts? I'm generally in favor of meaningful identifiers, with correct spelling.

Comment: Oh sorry. The input should be a string and when i tested it I used "abbcccdddd". You are right with the umlauts but it shouldn't change anything?

Comment: Two suggestions: Change "print" to "println" inside the loop, so that you can see the output immediately, and change the condition to `i<s.length()-2`.

Comment: With your data string, it definitely executes the loop, but fails with ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan - because source code is usually saved in ascii or in an 8-bit encoding. There is no defined standard between text editors on how to display charaters in the upper ascii range (128-255). It's usually dependent on the system locale. It might look ok one one machine, but when shared with someone else who uses a different editor in a different language....

Comment: I made the suggested changes but I still get no output from the methode. @PatriciaShanahan what does a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException mean?

Comment: @user3788064: the documentation, and google, are your friends: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.html

Comment: I'm just wondering, looking at the other answers. Is it wrong to actually take the asker's code and find the problems in it and correct it, then tell what problems were found to help the asker learn? Is it right to actually chuck that asker's attempts in the bin and give your own *pristine, fully functional, efficient* code as a replacement? **Where is the learning in it?** @user3788064 Please see my answer if you are looking to learn what's wrong with your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have corrected the code and gotten your expected result: `ABBC3D4`

- All array accesses must be within the array range. When you access `[i+2]` ensure your `i` value is always `< length-2`. (In other words, the index you're accessing (`i+2`) must always be `< length`.)
- With the *while* loop, it's a little trickier as `[i+Zähler]` must also be `< length` but `Zähler` can be any value. For this I added `(i+Zähler) < s.length()` as a check. It must be before `a[i] == a[i+Zähler]` as it needs to be evaluated first.
- Same goes for your original code: `i = i + Zähler`. You were overshooting by 1, so I had to add `- 1`. It ensured `print(a[i])` will not fail, by negating the effect of the **last** `Zähler++`.
- `println(a[i] + Zähler)` will print the numeric sum of `a[i]` added with `Zähler` (a *char* value is an integer *at heart*). Clearly this is not what you want, so I split it.
- I also added the check `if (Zähler != 0)` as you didn't want zeros printed.
- The `print` function, instead of `println`, prints on the same line.
- *Something I didn't correct in the code below:* When you're accessing an array in a for loop, the loop parameters should better use the length of that same array. So by right, you should be using `a.length`, not `s.length()`.
- *Something else:* Try rewriting the program using `String.charAt()`.

The working program is on Ideone [here (link)](http://ideone.com/4qafH4).

```
static void codieren(String s){
    int Zähler = 0;
    char[] a = s.toUpperCase().toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i<s.length()-2; i++){
        if (a[i] == a[i+1] && a[i] ==a[i+2]){
            Zähler = 3;
            while ((i+Zähler) < s.length() && a[i] == a[i+Zähler]) {
                Zähler++;
            }
            i = i + Zähler - 1;
        }
        System.out.print(a[i]);
        if (Zähler != 0) {
            System.out.print(String.valueOf(Zähler));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Up voting requires a reputation of 15 or higher. I am afraid I can't do that ADTC

Comment: Oh yeah *(embarrassed)*. Well, when you have the rep. `:)` Welcome to Stack Overflow. Hope you find the site useful! *PS:* Thanks @shekharsuman

Answer (score 1):

This is really a comment, but I need to include formatted output and code.

I think the problem may be a combination of a program failing due to an exception and an output method that is not showing the prior output on exception.

I used System.out.println to output in a program based on the question source code, and got:

```
65
66
66
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 10
    at Test.codieren(Test.java:8)
    at Test.main(Test.java:18)
71
```

ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException means that you attempted to access an array using an index outside the range 0 through length-1, using an index that does not exist, in this case 10.

My modified program is:

```
public class Test {
  static void codieren(String s) {
    int Zähler = 0;
    char[] a = s.toUpperCase().toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i <= s.length() - 1; i++) {
      if (a[i] == a[i + 1] && a[i] == a[i + 2]) {
        Zähler = 3;
        while (a[i] == a[i + Zähler])
          Zähler++;
        i = i + Zähler;
      }
      System.out.println(a[i] + Zähler);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {
    String s = "abbcccdddd";
    codieren(s);
  }
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify: this code still causes ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Comment: @laune Yes - I have not attempted to fix the loop logic, just to make it clear that the loop is executing.

Answer (score 1):

Your print statement prints the next char instead of printing the current one.
You have to:

- Print a[i] before you check for occurances
- Set the default value of Zaeler to 1.

So this is how your method should look like:

```
static void codieren(String s){
    char[] a = s.toUpperCase().toCharArray();
    for (int i = 0; i<s.length()-1; i++){
        int Zähler = 1;        
        Out.print(a[i]);
        if (a[i] == a[i+1] && a[i] ==a[i+2]){
            Zähler = 3;
            while (a[i] == a[i+Zähler]) Zähler++;   
            i = i + Zähler; 
        }
        Out.println("(" + Zähler + ")");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would start by writing a routine to count the consecutive occurances of a character in the array,

```
private static int countOccur(char[] arr, int st, int end) {
  final char ch = arr[st]; // 'st' is start. 
  int count = 1;
  for (; count < end - st; count++) { // <-- don't exceed the array boundary
    if (ch != arr[st + count]) { // <-- break if not the same character
      break;
    }
  }
  return count; // <-- return the count
}
```

Next, I'd modify `codieren(String)` to return a `String` (instead of being `void`, make the caller display the result - e.g. separation of concerns),

```
static String codieren(String s) {
  if (s == null) { // <-- handle corner cases.
    return null;
  }
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); // <-- for building the return String.
  char[] a = s.toUpperCase().toCharArray();
  for (int i = 0; i < a.length;) { // <-- we will increment by occurrences.
    int occur = countOccur(a, i, a.length); // <-- get the occurrences count.
    if (occur > 2) { // <-- 3 or more are LETTER then COUNT.
      sb.append(a[i]).append(occur);
    } else { // <-- Must be 2 or fewer.
      for (int t = 0; t < occur; t++) {
        sb.append(a[i]);
      }
    }
    i += occur; // <-- increment 'i'.
  }
  return sb.toString(); // <-- return the result.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative algorithm using "lookback" which IMHO is more maintainable (the length cutoff is not part of the scanning phase in lookback algorithm).

Steps:

1. Scan through the characters
2. Whenever there is a 'change', decide what to do with the sequence
   availlable till now
3. Continue the scan

This splits the work into two parts... "scan for edges" and "represent last sequence" which can be coded in a modular fashion.

```
public static String getCollapsed(String inString) {
    char[] chars = inString.toUpperCase().toCharArray();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(inString.length());
    char curChar = ' ';
    char lastChar = ' ';
    int lastCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        curChar = chars[i];
        if (i != 0) {
            if (curChar != lastChar) {
                sb.append(getRepresentation(lastChar, lastCount));
                lastCount = 0;
            }
        }
        lastChar = curChar;
        lastCount++;
    }
    sb.append(getRepresentation(lastChar, lastCount));
    return sb.toString();
}

private static String getRepresentation(char c, int count) {
    String s = "";
    if (count == 1) s = "" + c;
    else if (count == 2) s = "" + c + c;
    else s = "" + c + count;
    return s;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getCollapsed("AAAABCCDDDD"));

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will need to look into your solution when I have more time aviable.

Comment: @user3788064 Edited it... its more modular now.

Answer (score 1):

what about use two whiles

```
i = 0;
counter = 0;
currentchar=s[0]
stringbuffer outputstr;

while i < s.length
  {
   while s[i]==currentchar and i < s.length
     {
      counter +=1;
      i+=1;
     }

   if (counter== 1) 
      { outputstr.append(currentchar); }
   elseif (counter==2)
      { outputstr.append(currentchar);
        outputstr.append(currentchar);
      }
   else
      { outputstr.append(currentchar);
        outputstr.append(counter.toString);
      }

   currentchar = s[i];
   counter = 0;
  }
```

Comment: Does it give the intended results? If so its a nice solution too!

Comment: Yes, does it, you can try :)